# How to determine x, y coordinates when adding text in metafor

Tags: r, text, r-forestplot, metafor

I’m using the metafor package to create Forest plots in R. I’d like to add text to my plots to create labels using the text() function. I’m wondering what the simplest way is to determine the x,y coordinates of where I want my text to go. Currently I just guess and see how it looks and then edit as necessary. Is there a way to overlay a grid over my plot or something to guide me (and then remove it after)?
Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the # of rows and columns in your table text?

Answer (score 1):

Start by saving what `forest()` returns:

```
x <- forest(res)
```

And then take a look at `x`. Among other things, it contains `xlim` and `ylim`, which are the x-axis and y-axis limits. Try this:

```
abline(v=x$xlim)
abline(h=x$ylim)
```

Also useful:

```
text(x$xlim[1], x$rows, x$rows, xpd=NA)
```

I hope this helps.